# bootstrap input group alignment issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Creating a input group in bootstrap 4 but one of the buttons seems to be out of alignment.

here is my code

```
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="upload file...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">browse<input name="derfile" type="file" style="display: none;"></label>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0j0gmbjn/)

appreciate some assistance

Comment: changing your label tag to a button tag also aligns them for some reason, maybe an issue with the `input-group-btn` class and the label tag? ex: https://jsfiddle.net/0j0gmbjn/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result use below

```
.btn{
  vertical-align:top
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/0j0gmbjn/3/

Comment: Glad my answer helped you :)